# how to pass redirection to program while debugging with gdb

Tags: gdb

I'm entering the following on the linux command line:

```
./generate 10 8 | ./find 257
```

I would like to run gdb on the find command while piping output to it and passing it a parameter. How do you do that? 
    ./generate 10 8 | gdb ./find 257

Doesn't work of course. Can't figure it out:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a named pipe:

```
mknod /tmp/pipe p
./generate 10 8 > /tmp/pipe
gdb --args ./find 257
(gdb) run < /tmp/pipe
```